# How to open a file and edit its content in groovy script

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have a Makefile in my Jenkins job's workspace, that I want to edit out certain parts from and then save it, before running next part of the script that uses this Makefile.

the part that I want to cut out is this-

```
PUMP_MARKER:=,cpp
ifneq (,$(findstring $(PUMP_MARKER), $(DISTCC_HOSTS)))
PUMP:=pump
else
PUMP:=
endif
```

I am looking for some shell command that I could put in my groovy script, that will open up this file and remove this above mentioned part, save it and then move on.

I'm not good with shell so I cant possible figure this out on my own.

Here is how my groovy script looks like-

```
stage('Build'){
  dir ("$WORKSPACE/$SVN_TAG") {
    Here- I want to insert some shell command to edit that file out
  }
}
```

Could any please suggest some ideas to implement this.

**Note 1-** I know I could just vi that file and manually do this but I want to do this for multiple jobs and I'm genuinely looking for something that I can just paste in my every groovy script and automatically do this.

**Note 2-** It doesn't have to be shell, it can be any language as long as I can run it inside my groovy script and it gets the job done.

Comment: "I am looking for some shell command that I could put in my groovy script, that will open up this file and remove this above mentioned part, save it and then move on." - In particular do you need/want it to be a shell command?

Comment: not necessarily has to be shell if It is groovy im fine with that too, its just that I have done similar thing in the past and I used shell for this, and it was easy for me to use inside my groovy script. So that why I asked for shell.

Comment: How would you do it automatically [outside of Jenkins](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the patch tool like this-

```
patch foo.txt <<'END'
1,6d0
< PUMP_MARKER:=,cpp
< ifneq (,$(findstring $(PUMP_MARKER), $(DISTCC_HOSTS)))
< PUMP:=pump
< else
< PUMP:=
< endif
END
```

The script calls patch on the file to be modified (in this case foo.txt). The patch tool then also gets on the standard input the diff it shall apply. This is in the code below achieved using the "here document" mechanism from the shell, see the << followed by the quoted identifier END. Quoting END is necessary to ensure the subsequent diff text is not subject to expansions.